Formation energy of material in Quantum ESPRESSO
I am doing DFT calculation implemented in Quantum ESPRESSO. So I want to calculate the formation energy H of a 2D material wich is including N atom.
As you may know it is given by: H = Etot (N atom) - N*E(One atom)
Etot(N atom): is the total energy can be extracted from SCF output file.
How can we get E(one atom)?

You need to perform a single-point DFT calculation for each atom type in your system. Additionally, use a large cell to prevent self-interaction in the single-atom calculation.
